# Rails: how to create roles dynamically to Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I followed rolify's tutorial learnt some basic usages. https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial

For now I the only way I can do to create role is something like `user.add_role "admin"` in console.
What I want is to create roles by adding resources' actions, then admin user is able to assign roles to users.
I do not know how to achieve this, I made a draft to show my purpose.
Anybody could give me some ideas to make this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

create a model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true 
  scopify
end
```

Use that model as regular in form. This way you'll be able to create new roles.

If you want to add roles through user model, from e.g. dropdown select, grab Roles.all and pass it to your select.

Comment: why do you allow nil for the resource_type?  If your role is not linked to a resource it should not be valid.(?)

Comment: That model code, is actually what is in rolify gem so probably `allow_nil` is necessary internally by rolify. You actually can even not define this model. But you should do it just for a better control of it, to know "that it's there", and for later logic that you will potentionally need to implement on role, so you'll know where to add it